# python json object serialization strange results

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am experiencing a strange serialization "effect" that I cannot figure out why it is happening.

Essentially, one property is being represented as expected and another is not.
For example, based on the test below I am expecting to get:
{"source_system": "ABC", "target_system": "DEF"}
not
{"source_system": ["ABC"], "target_system": "DEF"}

Seems to think the one property source_system is a tuple but I cannot figure out why... likely I am being blind.

I get the same result with json library as with jsonpickle as shown in the example

```
import json
import jsonpickle

class testclass(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 _source_system = "",
                 _target_system = ""
                 ):

        self.source_system = _source_system,
        self.target_system = _target_system

    def to_JSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)    
        # return jsonpickle.encode(self, unpicklable=False)   


def main():
    test = testclass(_source_system = 'ABC', _target_system='DEF')

    print(test.to_JSON())                 
    print(jsonpickle.encode(test, unpicklable=False))
    print(jsonpickle.encode(test))

#============================================================================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the results are:

```
{
    "source_system": [
        "ABC"
    ], 
    "target_system": "DEF"
}
{"source_system": ["ABC"], "target_system": "DEF"}
{"py/object": "__main__.testclass", "source_system": {"py/tuple": ["ABC"]}, "target_system": "DEF"}
```

Why does it think source_system is a tuple and putting it in [] list brackets ? And, why are both properties not be treated/serialized the same ?

Comment: this is SO strange. I copied and pasted the class definition and renamed it - same results.  **then I re-typed the class def and it works as expected**.  possibly strange characters or ???  I did not see any obvious.

Comment: There is a comma at the end of the line 'self.source_system = _source_system'. When removed the result is the one you expect

Comment: thank you finmor - for the life of me I couldn't see that comma!. it looks like you had the correct answer first but you did so in a comment not an answer so I am unsure how to give you the credit or if I have to give the answer credit to Nikita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
self.source_system = _source_system,
```

has a trailing comma, so `self.source_system` *is* a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by **@fimnor** removing the comma inside your `__init__` function should do the trick. (May be he will make his comment in an answer, mine here just to explain.)

```
class testclass(object):
    def __init__(self,
             _source_system = "",
             _target_system = ""
             ):

    self.source_system = _source_system,
    self.target_system = _target_system

def to_JSON(self):
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)    
    # return jsonpickle.encode(self, unpicklable=False)
```

The comma after `_source_system` in your `__init__` makes it a one-tuple and therefore it is converted to JavaScript array. `self.source_system = _source_system,` is the same as `self.source_system = (_source_system,)`.